# Flex sort Datagrid with custom compareFunction (sort numbers numerical and text alphanumerical)

Tags: apache-flex, sorting, datagrid, compare

I need following result.

All numbers use numeric sorting and all strings use alphanumeric sort. Further more , the numeric values should be listed before the string values:

Example:
before "i","9","89","0045","b","x"

after "9","0045","89","b","i","x"

My current code looks like this: (numeric sort works but my strings are distributed to the top and bottom?! -> "b","x","9","0045","89","i")

```
 public function compareFunction(obj1:Object, obj2:Object):int {
  var id1:String = (obj1 as WdProblem).id;
  var id2:String = (obj2 as WdProblem).id;

  if(id1.replace(' ', '') == "n") {
    var sdld:int = 0;
  }

  var num1:int = Number(id1);
  var num2:int = Number(id2);

  if(stringIsAValidNumber(id1) && stringIsAValidNumber(id2)) {
    if(num1 == num2) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      if(num1 > num2) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    }
  } else if(!stringIsAValidNumber(id1) && !stringIsAValidNumber(id2)) {
    return ObjectUtil.compare(id1, id2);
      //return compareString(id1, id2);

  } else if(!stringIsAValidNumber(id1) && stringIsAValidNumber(id2)) {
    return 1;
  } else if(stringIsAValidNumber(id1) && !stringIsAValidNumber(id2)) {
    return -1;
  }

  return -1;
}

private function stringIsAValidNumber(s:String):Boolean {
  return Boolean(s.match("[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?"));
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to add a little preface to your question to provide some context to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to break it down into it's constituent parts especially if you have a scenario like this with 1 or more priority sorts. The key is to move onto the next sort only when the first sort returns they are equal.

For your case, I would build 2 sorts, one for numeric and the other for alpha-numeric, then your main sort can prioritize these by calling the sub-sort.

For example I have something similar:

```
private function sort2DimensionsByIncomeVsTime(a:OLAPSummaryCategory, b:OLAPSummaryCategory, fields:Array = null):int
{
    var sort:OLAPSort = new OLAPSort();
    var incomeSort:int = sort.sortIncome(a, b);
    var nameSort:int = sort.sortName(a, b);
    var yrSort:int = sort.sortYear(a, b);
    var moSort:int = sort.sortMonth(a, b);

    if (incomeSort == 0)
    {
        if (nameSort == 0)
        {
           if (yrSort == 0) 
           {
               //trace(a.name, a.year, a.month, 'vs:', b.name, b.year, b.month, 'month sort:', moSort);
               return moSort;
           }
           else return yrSort;
        }
        else return nameSort;
    }
    else return incomeSort;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use following sort function for AlphaNumeric sorting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    creationComplete="onCC()"
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
            import mx.utils.StringUtil;

            import spark.collections.Sort;
            import spark.collections.SortField;

            public function onCC():void
            {
                var acAlphaNumericString:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
                acAlphaNumericString.addItem({ name: "NUM10071" });
                acAlphaNumericString.addItem({ name: "NUM9999" });
                acAlphaNumericString.addItem({ name: "9997" });
                acAlphaNumericString.addItem({ name: "9998" });
                acAlphaNumericString.addItem({ name: "9996" });
                acAlphaNumericString.addItem({ name: "9996F" });
                acAlphaNumericString.addItem({ name: "i" });
                acAlphaNumericString.addItem({ name: "9" });
                acAlphaNumericString.addItem({ name: "89" });
                acAlphaNumericString.addItem({ name: "0045" });
                acAlphaNumericString.addItem({ name: "b" });
                acAlphaNumericString.addItem({ name: "x" });

                var sf:SortField = new SortField("name");
                sf.compareFunction = function(o1:Object, o2:Object):int
                {
                    return compare(o1.name, o2.name);
                }
                var sort:Sort = new Sort();
                sort.fields = [ sf ];
                acAlphaNumericString.sort = sort;
                acAlphaNumericString.refresh();

                for each (var o:Object in acAlphaNumericString)
                    trace(o.name);
            }

            public static function compare(firstString:String, secondString:String):int
            {
                if (secondString == null || firstString == null)
                    return 0;
                var lengthFirstStr:int = firstString.length;
                var lengthSecondStr:int = secondString.length;
                var index1:int = 0;
                var index2:int = 0;
                while (index1 < lengthFirstStr && index2 < lengthSecondStr)
                {
                    var ch1:String = firstString.charAt(index1);
                    var ch2:String = secondString.charAt(index2);
                    var space1:String = "";
                    var space2:String = "";
                    do
                    {
                        space1 += ch1;
                        index1++;
                        if (index1 < lengthFirstStr)
                            ch1 = firstString.charAt(index1);
                        else
                            break;
                    } while (isDigit(ch1) == isDigit(space1.charAt(0)));
                    do
                    {
                        space2 += ch2;
                        index2++;
                        if (index2 < lengthSecondStr)
                            ch2 = secondString.charAt(index2);
                        else
                            break;
                    } while (isDigit(ch2) == isDigit(space2.charAt(0)));

                    var str1:String = new String(space1);
                    var str2:String = new String(space2);
                    var result:int;
                    if (isDigit(space1.charAt(0)) && isDigit(space2.charAt(0)))
                    {
                        var firstNumberToCompare:int = parseInt(StringUtil.trim(str1));
                        var secondNumberToCompare:int = parseInt(StringUtil.trim(str2));
                        result = ObjectUtil.numericCompare(firstNumberToCompare, secondNumberToCompare);
                    }
                    else
                        result = ObjectUtil.compare(str1, str2);

                    if (result != 0)
                        return result;
                }
                return lengthFirstStr - lengthSecondStr;

                function isDigit(ch:String):Boolean
                {
                    var code:int = ch.charCodeAt(0);
                    return code >= 48 && code <= 57;
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```